# Android Modal Dialog implemented Singleton pattern

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, modal-dialog, singleton

**_________________MY SINGLETON MODAL DIALOG CLASS_________________**

```
⁃   public class CustomDialogMsgOneBtn
⁃   {
⁃   
⁃      private static CustomDialogMsgOneBtn _instance;
⁃   
⁃      private UIHandler uiHandler;
⁃      public Context _context;
⁃      public Dialog _dialog;
⁃      private Object synchObject = new Object();
⁃   
⁃      private TextView _tvDialogTitle;
⁃      private TextView _tvDialogMessage;
⁃      private String _dialogTitle;
⁃      private String _dialogMessage;
⁃      private Button _btnDialogOk;
⁃      private String _btnTextOk;
⁃   
⁃      private CustomDialogMsgOneBtn()
⁃      {
⁃   
⁃      }
⁃      public static CustomDialogMsgOneBtn getInstance()
⁃      {
⁃         if( _instance == null )
⁃         {
⁃            _instance = new CustomDialogMsgOneBtn();
⁃         }
⁃         return _instance;
⁃      }
⁃   
⁃      public void setTitleAndMessage( String title, String msg )
⁃      {
⁃         this._dialogTitle = title;
⁃         this._dialogMessage = msg;
⁃      }
⁃   
⁃      public void initDialog( Context c )
⁃      {
⁃         _context = c;
⁃      }
⁃   
⁃      public void setButtonTextOk( String sText )
⁃      {
⁃         this._btnTextOk = sText;
⁃      }
⁃   
⁃      private void constructUiThread()
⁃      {
⁃         HandlerThread uiThread = new HandlerThread( "UIHandler" );
⁃         uiThread.start();
⁃         uiHandler = new UIHandler( uiThread.getLooper() );
⁃      }
⁃   
⁃      public void show()
⁃      {
⁃         try
⁃         {
⁃            constructUiThread();
⁃   
⁃            uiHandler.sendEmptyMessage( 0 );
⁃   
⁃            synchronized( synchObject )
⁃            {
⁃               try
⁃               {
⁃                  synchObject.wait();
⁃               }
⁃               catch( InterruptedException e )
⁃               {
⁃                  e.printStackTrace();
⁃               }
⁃            }
⁃   
⁃         }
⁃         catch( Exception e )
⁃         {
⁃            e.printStackTrace();
⁃         }
⁃   
⁃      }
⁃   
⁃      public void dismissDialog()
⁃      {
⁃         _dialog.dismiss();
⁃      }
⁃   
⁃      private final class UIHandler extends Handler
⁃      {
⁃   
⁃         public View.OnClickListener btnListener = new View.OnClickListener()
⁃         {
⁃   
⁃            @Override
⁃            public void onClick( View v )
⁃            {
⁃   
⁃               int id = v.getId();
⁃               if( id == R.id.btnDialogOk )
⁃               {
⁃                  Log.d( "dialog Ok", "Ok" );
⁃   
⁃                  notifySync();
⁃               }
⁃   
⁃            }
⁃         };
⁃   
⁃         public DialogInterface.OnDismissListener dialogOnDismissListener = new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener()
⁃         {
⁃   
⁃            @Override
⁃            public void onDismiss( DialogInterface dialog )
⁃            {
⁃   
⁃               notifySync();
⁃               Log.d( "dialog being dismissed", "dismiss ang dialog" );
⁃            }
⁃         };
⁃   
⁃         public UIHandler( Looper looper )
⁃         {
⁃            super( looper );
⁃         }
⁃   
⁃         @Override
⁃         public void handleMessage( Message msg )
⁃         {
⁃            _dialog = new Dialog( _context );
⁃            _dialog.requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
⁃            _dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside( true );
⁃            _dialog.setContentView( R.layout.dialog_message_one_button );
⁃            _dialog.setOnDismissListener( dialogOnDismissListener );
⁃   
⁃            _tvDialogTitle = (TextView)_dialog.findViewById( R.id.txtDialogTitle );
⁃            _tvDialogMessage = (TextView)_dialog.findViewById( R.id.txtDialogMsg );
⁃            _btnDialogOk = (Button)_dialog.findViewById( R.id.btnDialogOk );
⁃   
⁃            _tvDialogTitle.setText( _dialogTitle );
⁃            _tvDialogMessage.setText( _dialogMessage );
⁃            _btnDialogOk.setText( _btnTextOk );
⁃   
⁃            _btnDialogOk.setOnClickListener( btnListener );
⁃   
⁃            _dialog.show();
⁃   
⁃         }
⁃   
⁃         private void notifySync()
⁃         {
⁃            synchronized( synchObject )
⁃            {
⁃               _dialog.dismiss();
⁃               synchObject.notifyAll();
⁃            }
⁃         }
⁃   
⁃      }// end UIHanlder class
⁃   
⁃   } //end Class
```

**________________HOW I CALL IT ON MY ACTIVITY CLASS_____________**

```
CustomDialogMsgTwoBtn.getInstance().initDialog(this);
CustomDialogMsgTwoBtn.getInstance().setLeftAndRightButtonText( "cancel", "accept" );
CustomDialogMsgTwoBtn.getInstance().setTitleAndMessage( "Custom Dialog", "test msg" );
CustomDialogMsgTwoBtn.getInstance().show();
```

09-16 08:41:42.934: I/InputDispatcher(286): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{41c8f4f8 token=Token{41c05558 ActivityRecord{4205b5a0 u0  com.templatea/com.templatea.MainActivity}}} - Window{41995bf0 u0 com.example.esf_templatea/com.templatea.MainActivity}.  It has been 5008.4ms since event, 5006.8ms     since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because the focused window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.
    09-16 08:41:42.934: I/WindowManager(286): Input event dispatching timed out sending to com.example/com.templatea.MainActivity
    09-16 08:41:43.184: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 7296 SIG: 3
    09-16 08:41:43.194: I/dalvikvm(7296): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    09-16 08:41:43.255: I/dalvikvm(7296): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    09-16 08:41:43.255: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 286 SIG: 3
    09-16 08:41:43.255: I/dalvikvm(286): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    09-16 08:41:43.745: I/dalvikvm(286): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    09-16 08:41:43.745: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 404 SIG: 3
    09-16 08:41:43.745: I/dalvikvm(404): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    09-16 08:41:43.854: I/dalvikvm(404): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    09-16 08:41:43.864: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 446 SIG: 3
    09-16 08:41:43.864: I/dalvikvm(446): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    09-16 08:41:43.985: I/dalvikvm(446): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    09-16 08:41:44.645: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3213K, 50% free 6742K/13296K, paused 4ms+10ms, total 113ms
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286): ANR in com.emplatea (com.templatea/com.templatea.MainActivity)
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286): Load: 0.2 / 0.15 / 0.09
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286): CPU usage from 17189ms to 0ms ago:
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286):   1.1% 46/adbd: 0.2% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 180 minor
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286):   1.1% 286/system_server: 0.9% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 67 minor
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286):   0% 404/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286):   0% 446/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286): 4.9% TOTAL: 2.1% user + 2.6% kernel + 0.1% softirq
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286): CPU usage from 1502ms to 2050ms later:
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286):   5.5% 286/system_server: 3.7% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 2 minor
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286):     9.2% 303/ActivityManager: 5.5% user + 3.7% kernel
    09-16 08:41:45.234: E/ActivityManager(286): 7.2% TOTAL: 7.2% user + 0% kernel
    09-16 08:41:45.375: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1595K, 57% free 5837K/13296K, paused 75ms, total 76ms
    09-16 08:41:45.505: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1034K, 59% free 5464K/13296K, paused 72ms, total 73ms
    09-16 08:41:45.515: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

My problem is that this is perfectly working and convinient for me to use a modal dialog implemented in a singleton pattern. it will pause the instruction pointer on the Activity and proceed to showing the Dialog under Handlter thread( you can see this on the singleton class) . but im not sure why when i press the "back button" it will crash my application and freeze it. hope somebody can help me out. :(

Comment: Please add the stacktrace (LogCat).

Comment: doing things like that you're asking for troubles,  please don't fight against androd framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I cannot do what i want to do. this is based on how Android works.

dissabled the code below

```
 synchronized( synchObject )
        {
           try
           {
              synchObject.wait();
           }
```

now i just used communicator pattern to handle the events and result of the dialog.

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don´t do that!
Once you stop the UI thread, Android system will present a dialog to the user for to try to force closing!!

Use the managed dialogs instead http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html 
Been deprecated,though